# Cross domain ajax request success event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is the scenario which is surprisingly simple:

I send an ajax request which targets a different domain:

```
$(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.drivescheduler.com/functions.php?function=getHighSchools&code=" + $("#code").val(),
            type: 'get',
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
            },
            success: function(x, status, xhr){
                alert();
            }
        });
    });
```

On the domain which receives the ajax request, I've properly configured CORS headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://temp.jfdin.net');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-MD5, X-Alt-Referer');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

And I can see the request being sent and the proper response being received through Chrome Debug Tools, but I get no `alert()`.
In other words, the success event never gets fired.
Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add an error handler. See if there are any errors.

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: there is something in the console?

Comment: What are you alerting? There is no parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The URL you are requesting responds with a JSON content type but an HTML body.

jQuery will fail to parse the HTML as JSON and error.

Comment: Thanks that did it. What I'm surprised about is why JQuery does not throw any particular errors in this case. I checked my console log and everything seemed fine.

Comment: Because jQuery has a specific `error` handler function where you can see the errors. It just doesn't throw a JavaScript exception.